# Zend Framework: how to remove rendered views in the controller?

Tags: zend-framework, view, render

i want to render one of these sets of views:

1. head
2. body-$id1
3. foot

OR

1. head
2. body-$id2
3. foot

which set exsists.

i do it like this:

```
try {
    $this->render("head");
    $this->render("body-$id1");
    $this->render("foot");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->render("head");
    $this->render("body-$id2");
    $this->render("foot");  
}
```

but it causes the `head` view be rendered twice if body-$id1 does not exists.

do you have a better solution?

**in another saying, may i check the existance of `body-$id1` before rendering it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it'll run any valid script in the "try" block, but if it fails, it'll render all the content in the "catch" block. So you probably want something more like:

```
$this->render("head");
try {
    $this->render("body-$id1");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->render("body-$id2");
}
$this->render("foot");
```

I don't see an API method to check if a view exists, but you could write a controller helper that just gets the path to your view scripts and uses `file_exists` to check if "body-{$id1}" exists in that path.